Using Powershell WebAdministration module with limited domain account (not admin user)
I need to deploy a website using PowerShell scripts to stop/start a remote website, copy the items to the remote application folders but using a domain account having limited acces to the remote server.
These are some of the PowerShell cmdlets to use:

Stop/Star-Website
Copy-Item to copy to the remote website using a remote session of this limited user.
Other cmdlets to create secure credentials, make backups, etc.

By adding the account to the "Remote Management Users", it can deal with PowerShell remote session but still it is unable to Stop and Start the website because lack of elevated privileges. For example, the following step would stop the website
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "RemoteServer" -ScriptBlock { Stop-Website "RemoteWebsite" } -Credential $credential

But it fails with the following error message: "Process should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data."
I had added the user to the website's "IIS Manager Permissions" feature as Allowed user, but with same result. If I add it to the Administrator group, it works fine.
What other configuration is required, excluding adding the account to the Administrators group, to be able to use the WebAdministration module?

You can add the Web-Administration permission to the Stop-Website cmdlet.  Stop-Website permissions is set so only an admin can run the cmdlet.
